# Logstash command line on Windows doesn't accept path with spaces

Tags: windows, logstash

I am trying to set up Logstash as a service on a Windows box, but it doesn't seem to accept spaces in paths. If I run the following command:

```
logstash.bat agent -f "C:\Program Files (x86)\Logstash\config\setup.conf"
```

then Logstash complains with an error "Files was unexpected at this time".

I know that Logstash is not happy with backslashes, so I also tried with forward slashes, but no luck. So I am beginning to suspect that Logstash doesn't accept spaces in paths on Windows, can anyone confirm that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like maybe there is a bug in either the .BAT that prevents names with spaces from being used.  You'll need to use the mangled format for the directory name (`dir /x "C:"` to see what the managed name is for your particular directory, but it'll probably be `PROGRA~1`)

If you really want to use a spaces in your name without mangling, you can patch the logstash.bat (modify the line that says `if "%*" == "deps"` to `if "%~1" == deps`) and then use `"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Logstash\\config\\setup.conf"` or `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Logstash/config/setup.conf"` as your command line argument.

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was to unset the `CLASSPATH` environment variable at the top of logstash.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set params='%*'
SET CLASSPATH=
SET JAVA_OPTS=
```